# Ruby named parameters with keywords

Tags: ruby

I'd love to use a method signature like:

```
def register(something, on:, for:)
```

This works, but I can't work out how to use "for" without causing a syntax error! Rather annoying, anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the method definition line that you posted, the problem is the usage of the `for` variable inside the method body. Since `for` is a reserved word, you cannot use it as a plain variable name, but you can use it as part of a hash. In your case that means you must resort to using arbitrary keyword arguments (`**opts`), but you can use the keyword_argument `for:` in the method call. You may want to raise an `ArgumentError` if the key is not present to emulate the behavior of the method signature you posted above.

```
def register(something, on:, **opts)
  raise ArgumentError, 'missing keyword: for' unless opts.has_key?(:for)
  for_value = opts[:for]

  puts "registering #{something} on #{on} for #{for_value}"
end

register 'chocolate chips', on: 'cookie'
# ArgumentError: missing keyword: for

register 'chocolate chips', on: 'cookie', for: 'cookie monster'
# registering chocolate chips on cookie for cookie monster
```

Comment: This is one way :) I was hoping not to deviate from the named params format though

Comment: I know its not very pretty, but it gets the job done and the invocation syntax is just as clean

Answer (score 3):

```
binding.local_variable_get(:for)
```

is a way I was thinking. Only works in ruby 2.1+ I think.

NOTE: Don't do this, I'm just interested in how you could get round it, you probably should just call your named parameter something else :)

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, **for** is a reserved keyword - looks like you just cannot use them in other way to how they were meant to use.
That's the whole purpose of reserving keywords.

Additional resources on which keywords are reserved in Ruby:

- http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Language-Basics/Rubysreservedwords.htm
- (thanks [@cremno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4231385/cremno) for this comment) Both links don't mention **ENCODING**. Also, since 2.2.0 Ruby comes with an official document: $ `ri ruby:keywords`

**UPD**

Actualy, you can still use **:for** symbol as a key in hash (let's say, options hash), so, you can write like this:

```
def test(something, options = {})
  puts something
  puts options.values.join(' and ')
end
```

and it works like charm:

```
[4] pry(main)> test 'arguments', :for => :lulz, :with => :care, :while => 'you are writing code' 
arguments
lulz and care and you are writing code
```

Comment: I know its a keyword, I mentioned that in the title. I asked if there was a way around it. some way to access it dynamically through the current binding or something?

Comment: @MichaelBaldry look into updated part - is it enough for you to use, or you meant some other way? BTW, in my humble opinion, usage of keywords in such manner can increase amount of "WTF?!" per line. ;)

Comment: Both links don't mention `__ENCODING__`. Also, since 2.2.0 Ruby comes with an official document: `$ ri ruby:keywords`.

Comment: I know it adds to the WTF/L, I'm just curious :)